# Adding list item when user does not have permissions question

Tags: list, permissions, splistitem

I am trying to programmatically add a list item to a SharePoint list. The code works fine when executed by a user with contribute permissions, but does not work when a user has view only. Funny thing is, i can debug through the same code with both users and it does not seem to fail on the user with read only.

I only want users to be able to add items to the list (which has a workflow to approve before they are visible) so giving the users contribute permissions will not work.

I tried running with elevated privileges but that did not work.

Is there a permissions setting to only allow add item ot list, or is there a way to programmatically bypass this issue?

This is the code i am working on right now:

```
                var siteId = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                        // Fetch the List
                        SPList list = web.Lists["List Name"];

                        //Add a new item in the List
                        SPListItem itemToAdd = list.Items.Add();
                        itemToAdd["Title"] = titlename;
                        itemToAdd.Update();
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Solved, run with elevated privileges grants you system account access, but you still cannot add an item with it. The full answer can be found on the second reply here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164626/impersonate-as-different-user-inside-the-webpart-code

Comment: Sounds like something is wrong with the code, can you post a snippet of it for us to look at?

Comment: This code looks fine.  Is there code that executes prior to this that may be failing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom permission level that allows adding but not editing.

See this [MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239%28v=office.14%29.aspx) about how to do that. You will want to copy the contribute permission but remove the edit permissions.

Comment: Simple, effective and no managed code is the way to go here.

Comment: In addition to my edit above, this will work as well so i marked it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are calling the `RunWithElevatedPrivileges()` outside the point where you are getting an SPSite reference otherwise it has no effect.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteUrl))
    {
    // do your stuff in here
    }
});
```