# edit list without permission in C#

Tags: development, permissions, edit

i need help wit this I want user to edit list items (insert) without having a permission of edit for that list in c# how can i do that?

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you targeting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using SystemAccount System Account.

```
SPUserToken sysToken = properties.Site.SystemAccount.UserToken;
using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(properties.Site.ID, sysToken))
{
   using (SPWeb elevateWeb = elevatedSite.OpenWeb())
   { 
       //your code here...
   }
}
```

BOUCHAALA AHMED

Comment: You are welcome Shams

Answer (score 1):

You can use SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges, here is an exemple :

```
Guid siteId = SPContext.Current.Site.ID;
Guid webId = SPContext.Current.Web.ID;

SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteId))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webId))
        {
            // Your code here
        }
    }
});
```

BOUCHAALA AHMED

Comment: every time i got this Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, I believe you can use impersonation to add list items in sharepoint list without having permission on list.

For more information, click [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67908/adding-list-item-when-user-does-not-have-permissions-question).

Impersonation in SP 2010, [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67908/adding-list-item-when-user-does-not-have-permissions-question).

Using SPTokens for impersonation. For more info [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0bd505cd-6d57-47e3-b302-7c141a0ba151/using-spusertoken-for-adding-a-list-item).

Please upvote if this answer helped you in any way.

Comment: in SP2013?? how can I

Comment: Use RunWithElevatedPrivileges() in C#, see first link for more information clarification.

Comment: every time i got this Sorry, this site hasn't been shared with you.

Comment: Great. Please upvote if this answer helped you in any way.